# Foreign Gift tax in USA

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax

My husband (on a H-1B visa for 5+ years) and I (on an F1 visa for 2 years) live in the Bay Area. We are planning on buying a house and, as we all know, houses are way too expensive here. My question:

How much money can we receive in the form of gift tax from our parents in India? I read online that there is a limit of $100k which will not be taxed in the USA. Does this mean 100k per head if my husband and I receive gifts from our respective parents?

Comment: Since in [this other question that you have asked](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/60803/5760) you claim to be on a h1b visa and wanting to _send_ $50K to your parents in India, perhaps you can coordinate with yourself (or your husband) so that the $50K to be sent by your husband to parents in India offsets the $100K that the parents will send the husband to buy a house in the US? That way, only $50K will need to be transferred (from India to US).

Answer (score 3):

As much as you want. There's no tax on gifts you *receive*. Gift tax is on the donor, i.e.: the person giving the gift.

The $100K limit is for reporting. Gifts of $100K or more per year from foreign sources must be disclosed on [form 3520](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-3520) attached to your tax return. But there's no tax. Read more [here](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Gifts-from-Foreign-Person).